# ITextSharp is not rendering nested unordered lists in the PDF

Tags: c#, html, .net, itext, pdf-generation

I am using ItextSharp to convert HTML to PDF. The PDF generation is working but the nested unordered lists are not getting rendered correctly. 
ITextShar version is 5.5.13.1 and ITextSharp.xmlworker version is 5.5.13.1

The HTML is shown correctly in the js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Lumaqox5/1/

But, the same HTML does not render correctly when converted to PDf.

HTML is shown below

```
       <div>
        <p class="letterText">You need to know:</p>
        <ul class="bulletPoint">
           <li class="letterText">This is the randon list text
              <ul>
                <li class="letterText">value1</li>
                <li class="letterText">value2</li>
                <li class="letterText">value3</li>
              </ul>
           some more rando text should show here.
          </li>
         <li class="letterText">The next list text here
            <ul>
              <li class="letterText">Next1</li>
              <li class="letterText">Next2</li>
            </ul>
              Random text
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

I am using the below C# code to convert HTML to PDF.

```
         static void Main(string[] args)
             {
        var template = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ITextSharpLGPL\ItextSharpCSS\HTMLPage2.html");
        byte[] pdf; // result will be her
        var cssText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ITextSharpLGPL\ItextSharpCSS\StyleSheet1.css");
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50f ,50f , 20f, 20f);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.Open();
            using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
            {
                using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(template)))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                }
            }
            document.Close();
            pdf = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
            var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Sample.pdf");
            File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, pdf);
        }
    }
```

The css file contents are

```
    body {
       }

    .letterText {
          font-size: 15px;
          font-family: 'Times New Roman';
      }

     .bulletPoint {
           list-style-type: disc;
        }

     .bulletPoint li > ul {
           list-style-type: circle;
          }
```

The HTML when cnverted to PDF looks like the below image

[image: HTML2PDF]

Could I get some help in getting the lists rendered correctly? TIA